# How to compile another project before compiling main project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, build

I have a solution with two executing projects. Users can execute project B from project A by pressing a button. Project A Debug folder contains the project B Debug folder, so it executes project B by the hardcoded path to that folder. If I want to make some changes in project B - I need to recompile project B and replace its Debug folder in project A Debug folder. I think it's not a smart and comfortable way from the point of architecture view. So I want to include such actions in project A build events, but I have never done it before, so I would be happy to hear your suggestions.

Comment: Isn't this what Build Solution does by default? Or you must have created several build configurations where you excluded projects from building. If you want to copy files after building, you can edit the *.csproj file and add a copy task in the AfterBuild target. Those are commented out in your csproj file.

Comment: If you add project B as a reference to project A you tell the compiler the dependency, so it does know that it should build B before A. Afterwards you right click in the solution explorer Project A - Dependencies - Projects - Project B, select properties and set Reference Output Assembly to false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this is to create a reference from A to B, so you coud access the (public) members of B from project A. This way, you could also run the code of B in the process of A, eliminating the need to start a separate process.

If you do have the requirement that you need to have a separate exe for B that runs in a separate process, there is another approach that requires more effort:

1. Do not create a reference from A to B, but use a **Project Dependency*** to make sure that B is compiled before A. You can configure project dependencies in a dialog that you access in the context menu of the solution or in the application menu Project -> Project Dependencies. After setting the dependency, you can check the build order on the second tab of the dialog.
2. Adjust the build of A to copy the output of B to the output folder. There are several ways to do this, one of the more advanced options is to add **Build Targets** to the project file of A that perform the copy and clean for the files. You have to unload project A and edit the project file (see context menu) and add code similar to the following:

---

```
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <ItemGroup>
      <AdditionalFiles Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\ProjectB\bin\$(Configuration)\ProjectB.*" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(AdditionalFiles)" DestinationFolder="$(OutputPath)" />
  </Target>
  <Target Name="AfterClean">
    <ItemGroup>
      <AdditionalFilesToDelete Include="$(OutputPath)\ProjectB.*" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Delete Files="@(AdditionalFilesToDelete)" />
  </Target>
```

Please see the [documentation on build targets](http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-targets?view=vs-2019) and note that the code above is only a sample that you need to adjust to your specific needs. For instance, it only works with the standard output paths.

Comment: thank you very much, it seems helpful, but as I've understood, project A must depend on project B. Now project B depends on A, and I can't change it. If I remove dependency B from A - VS says, that the dependency has been set by project system and can't be removed.

Comment: and yes, I need to have separated B

Comment: @ХарламовДаниил so you have a reference from B to A; you cannot change dependencies that exist due to project references. So if you want to follow the approach, you'd have to create a class library project C that contains the components that both A and B need. A and B reference C, but B does not reference project A anymore. Then you can set the dependency as required.

Comment: I've understood now, that in my solution I copy Debug folder of project B into Debug folder of project A so, that project A simply executes B. So it doesn't matter in what order projects are built. Thank you very much for your anwser)